# Access violation error on any page or drush

Tags: database, configuration

Recently started working with an inherited Drupal 8 website which I am trying to get up and running on my Mac OS X (Sierra) but I am getting this error with a stack trace every time I try run `drush` or simply visit the website. Any pointers on what is causing this and possibly how to fix would be appreciated.

```
    jc@~/Development/Sites/example-website/web $ drush
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1231 Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' in     [error]
/Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php:170
Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php(170): PDO->exec('SET sql_mode =
...')
#1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(376):
Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection::open(Array)
#2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(166):
Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection('default', 'default')
#3 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default')
#4 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(79):
call_user_func_array('Drupal\\Core\\Dat...', Array)
#5 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177):
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'database')
#6 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(264):
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('database', 1)
#7 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(62):
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array)
#8 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(177):
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'cache.container')
#9 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(508):
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.container')
#10 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Drupal/DrupalKernel.php(53):
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition()
#11 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(461):
Drush\Drupal\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer()
#12 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot8.php(146): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot()
#13 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc(354):
Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot8->bootstrap_drupal_full()
#14 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc(509): drush_bootstrap(5, 7)
#15 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/help.drush.inc(103): drush_bootstrap_max()
#16 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_core_help()
#17 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#18 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
#19 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#20 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66):
Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#21 /Library/WebServer/Documents/example-website/web/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#22 {main}
```

settings.local.php db details (Minus password obviously)

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
    'database' => 'example_website_drupal_db',
    'username' => 'exsiteuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'prefix' => '',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '3306',
    'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Apache is running PHP 7.0

Drupal Version: 8.2.7

MySql version: 8.0.11

Drush version 8.1.16 (I get an error trying to install 9 via composer)

Composer install has been run to get modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 8 doesn't support MySQL 8 yet. See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2966523) for the details.

For now you'll either need to downgrade to an earlier DBMS version, or apply the patch in the above issue.